# Using typedef'd struct in cython

Tags: python, c, typedef, cython

I have the following definition in the header file dcm.h:

```
typedef struct
{    
    double alpha;
    double gamma;
    double tau;
} ThetaDCM;
```

I want to import it in cython, so I have:

```
cdef extern from "dcm.h":

    ctypedef struct ThetaDCM:

        np.float64_t alpha
        np.float64_t gamma
        np.float64_t tau
```

Now I want to allocate memory to an array of ThetaDCM's. I have the following:

```
cdef ThetaDCM *c_theta = <ThetaDCM *> malloc(nt * nb * sizeof(ThetaDCM))

free(c_theta)
```

This did not compile and reported the following error:

```
error: ‘ThetaDCM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   __pyx_v_c_theta = ((ThetaDCM *)malloc(((__pyx_v_nt * __pyx_v_nb) * (sizeof(ThetaDCM)))));
```

There where other errors related to this one. If I define ThetaDCM outside the extern block, the code compiles without problem. Therefore, if I import Theta, cython cannot see my declaration. Is there any standard way to solve this?

**Edit:**

The header of my file was a bit more complicated than what I posted. It was

```
# ifdef __CUDACC__
# ifndef DDM_HEADER
# define DDM_HEADER

#include "math.h"
#include "curand_kernel.h"
#include "curand.h"
#include <stdio.h>
...
# endif 

# ifdef __CUDACC__
# define BDDM_EXTERN extern "C"
# else
# define BDDM_DEVICE
# endif

BDDM_EXTERN
int llh_m0t( double *x, double *y, double *u,
    double *theta, double *ptheta, int ny, int nt, double *llh);
...
typedef struct
{    
    double alpha;
    double gamma;
    double tau;
} ThetaDCM;

# endif
```

The directive on top is used to check if the compiler is nvcc, a compiler for cuda code. Now I realize that there was an error and that I should have had:

```
# ifndef DDM_HEADER
# define DDM_HEADER
# ifdef __CUDACC__

#include "math.h"
#include "curand_kernel.h"
#include "curand.h"
#include <stdio.h>
...
# endif

BDDM_EXTERN
int llh_m0t( double *x, double *y, double *u,
    double *theta, double *ptheta, int ny, int nt, double *llh);
...

typedef struct
{    
    double alpha;
    double gamma;
    double tau;
} ThetaDCM;
# endif
```

What confused me is that the *cython* code compiled despite of the # ifdef **CUDACC**. I used cython to wrap c functions defined inside the first #ifdef statement (like llh_m0t), so the confusing thing is that cython could see those function definitions.

Comment: Works fine here. Are you sure the `typedef` is in the header file?

Comment: _"header file dcm.c"_ `dcm.h` ?

Comment: Yes it is a typo, sorry.

Comment: @larsmans Yes I am. Did you try and did it worked? If that's true, the error should be somewhere else, although I'm sure that if I remove the code from the extern block, it compiles. Moreover, if I don't use ThetaDCM, the code compiles.

Comment: What about `cdef struct ThetaDCM *c_theta = <ThetaDCM *> malloc(nt * nb * sizeof(struct ThetaDCM))` ? (EDIT: [probably not  that](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#styles-of-struct-union-and-enum-declaration))

Comment: Is your Cython recent enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython does not provide support to `#define`  macro for conditional compilation as required by your header:

> *<sub>dcm.h</sub>*
>
> ```
> # ifdef __CUDACC__
>
> typedef struct
> {    
>     double alpha;
>     double gamma;
>     double tau;
> } ThetaDCM;
>
> # endif
> ```

A quick workaround:

> *<sub>dcm.pyh</sub>*
>
> ```
> #define __CUDACC__
> #include "dcm.h"
> ```

> *<sub>dcm.pyx</sub>*
>
> ```
> [...]
>
> cdef extern from "dcm.pyh":
> #                     ^^^
>     [...]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Probably an issue with an old (or too ... *beta* ?) version of *cython*.

I agree this is not really an answer -- mostly a very long comment... but this works for me using *cython 0.20.0*:

> *<sub>dcm.h</sub>*
>
> ```
> typedef struct
> {    
>     double alpha;
>     double gamma;
>     double tau;
> } ThetaDCM;
> ```

> *<sub>dcm.pyx</sub>*
>
> ```
> cimport numpy as np
> from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
>
> nt = 1
> nb = 1
>
> cdef extern from "dcm.h":
>
>     ctypedef struct ThetaDCM:
>
>         np.float64_t alpha
>         np.float64_t gamma
>         np.float64_t tau
>
> cdef ThetaDCM *c_theta = <ThetaDCM *> malloc(nt * nb * sizeof(ThetaDCM))
>
> print(hex(<long>c_theta))
>
> free(c_theta)
> ```

```
sh$ cython dcm.pyx
sh$ gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I../include/python3.4m/ -L../lib/python3.4/ dcm.c -o dcm.so
sh$ python3Python 3.4.1 (default, Aug 20 2014, 14:47:11) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dcm
0x23e44f0
```

Comment: I'm using a pretty recent version of cython: Cython version 0.21b1. However, I will test it again.

Comment: _"I will test it again"_ Don't hesitate ;) I put the complete listing and commands in the answer, could you stick with that at first, so we can compare our result.

Comment: @eaponte Just a wild idea: in your `dcm.h`, the structure definition wouldn't be wrapped in some kind of `#if ... #endif` ignored by Cython ?

Comment: You are right @Sylvain Leroux. The problem seems to be related to bug in my preprocessor directives and a weird behavior in cython. See my edits. Thank you!