# Texgenpack Wrapper - Compilation Problems

Tags: cython

I'm working on a wrapper for [texgenpack](https://github.com/hglm/texgenpack) for my [AssetStudio](https://github.com/Perfare/AssetStudio) [python port](https://github.com/K0lb3/UnityPy).
The goal of the wrapper is a conversion of texture types into a format that PIL can use.
Atm, I simply want to save the original texture as a file, then read it via texgenpack, convert it and feed the result to PIL.
(Later on the file r/w will be replaced by passing bytes.)

When I try to use

```py
    def decompress(self, dst_filetype : FileType = FileType.PNG):
        # init
        cdef Image *image = <Image *> malloc(sizeof(Image))

        src = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=self.filetype.name.lower(), delete=True)
        dst = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=dst_filetype.name.lower(), delete=True)

        #write image data to tempfile
        src.write(self.data)

        #load temp file as texture -> image
        load_image(<const char *>src.name, <int> self.filetype, *image)

        #save image as png
        save_image(*image, <const char> *dst.name, <int> dst_filetype)
```

I get the error

```
                #save image as png
                save_image(*image, <const char> *dst.name, <int> dst_filetype)
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

texgenpack.pyx:57:34: Expected an identifier or literal
```

I don't understand why the error shows up there, but not at load_image.
I tried multiple things, but pretty much all of them ended up in this error.

Since I mainly want to use it to convert textures I tried to circumvent
the problem by making a c function which does the load/save itself.

```c
void convert_stexture_to_simage(const char *filename, int filetype, const char *dstname) {
    Image image;
    load_image(filename, filetype, &image);
    save_image(&image, dstname, FILE_TYPE_PNG);
}
```

in image.c and added it to the header.

When I try to use this function via

```py
convert_stexture_to_simage(<const char *>src.name, <int> self.filetype,<const char *>dst.name)
```

the following error is produced

```
texgenpack.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl convert_stexture_to_simage(char const *,int,char const *)" (?convert_stexture_to_simage@@YAXPEBDH0@Z)
build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\texgenpack_py.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I hope that one of you can tell me how one of these two problems can be solved.

### Edit

Image is defined as

```cpp
typedef struct {
    unsigned int *pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
    int extended_width;
    int extended_height;
    int alpha_bits;         // 0 for no alpha, 1 if alpha is limited to 0 and 0xFF, 8 otherwise.
    int nu_components;      // Indicates the number of components.
    int bits_per_component;     // 8 or 16.
    int is_signed;          // 1 if the components are signed, 0 if unsigned.
    int srgb;           // Whether the image is stored in sRGB format.
    int is_half_float;      // The image pixels are combinations of half-floats. The pixel size is 64-bit.
} Image;
```

in the .pyx as

```py
    ctypedef struct Image:
        unsigned int* pixels
        int width
        int height
        int extended_width
        int extended_height
        int alpha_bits          # 0 for no alpha, 1 if alpha is limited to 0 and 0xFF, 8 otherwise.
        int nu_components       # Indicates the number of components.
        int bits_per_component  # 8 or 16.
        int is_signed           # 1 if the components are signed, 0 if unsigned.
        int srgb                # Whether the image is stored in sRGB format.
        int is_half_float       # The image pixels are combinations of half-floats. The pixel size is 64-bit.
```

based on [the 2nd answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544587/using-typedefd-struct-in-cython)

The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/K0lb3/texgenpack_py).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling pointers when wrapping C++ class with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554581/handling-pointers-when-wrapping-c-class-with-cython)

Comment: The duplicate suggestion only covers your first question though...

Comment: The first part shouldn't be a duplicate of that question.
I followed the advice of the 2nd answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544587/using-typedefd-struct-in-cython .

Comment: Side note: for the code listed in github, I see you are declaring python enums like `class FileTypeBit(IntEnum)`. You could use declarations like `cpdef enum FileTypeBit` instead to get C performance for enums used in your cython code for essentially free.

Comment: You might also want to consider moving your `cdef extern from "texgenpack_py.h":` block to a separate pxd file. This can help to separate clutter between whatever cython code you implement and the pre-existing interface provided by the original library.

Comment: As for your question about passing `Image` pointers to the external `load_image` and `save_image` functions, what happens if you replace `*image` (which should be `image[0]` in cython by the way, since `*` was hijacked by python for `*args` and `**kwargs`) with just `image`? You are already passing in a pointer in your cython code. Your C code for `convert_stexture_to_simage` is different since the `image` there is not a pointer to a malloced struct but an actual struct made on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem,
it was actually pretty laughable.

The problem was,
that the C source wasn't compiled,
so the function references in the header files couldn't link to any actual functions.

**setup.py**

```py
import os
from setuptools import Extension, setup
try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
except ImportError:
    cythonize = None

def ALL_C(folder, exclude = []):
    return [
        '/'.join([folder, f])
        for f in os.listdir(folder)
        if f[-2:] == '.c' and f not in exclude
    ]

extensions = [
        Extension(
                name = "texgenpy",
                sources = [
                    "texgen.pyx",
                    *ALL_C('texgenpack'),
                ],
                #language = "c++",
                include_dirs = [
                    "texgenpack",
                    "libfgen",
                    ],
        )
]
if cythonize:
    extensions = cythonize(extensions)

setup(ext_modules = extensions)
```

**correct cython code to load the image via texgenpack**

```py
cdef class TTexture:
    cdef Image image

    def __init__(self, srcfile : str, filetype : int = -1):
        if filetype == -1:
            filetype = KNOWN_FILE_TYPES.get(srcfile.rsplit('.')[1].upper(), 0x000)
        self.load(srcfile, filetype)

    def load(self, srcfile, filetype):
        # convert filepath to const char
        src_b = (u"%s" % srcfile).encode('ascii')
        cdef const char*src = src_b
        load_image(src, <int> filetype, &self.image)
```

**conversion to pillow image**

```py
    @property
    def image(self) -> PILImage:
        # prepare tmp image in case of required conversion
        cdef Image tmp_image
        clone_image(&self.image, &tmp_image)

        # convert image type
        if tmp_image.is_half_float:
            convert_image_from_half_float(&tmp_image, 0, 1.0, 1.0)
        elif tmp_image.bits_per_component != 8:
            print("Error -- cannot write PNG file with non 8-bit components.\n")
            return None

        if tmp_image.nu_components == 1: #grayscale
            img = PILImage.new('L', (tmp_image.width, tmp_image.height))
            img_data = img.load()
        elif tmp_image.alpha_bits > 0:
            img = PILImage.new('RGBA', (tmp_image.width, tmp_image.height))
            img_data = img.load()
            for y in range(tmp_image.height):
                for x in range(tmp_image.width):
                    img_data[y,x] = calc_color_rgba(tmp_image.pixels[y*tmp_image.height + x])
        else:
            img = PILImage.new('RGB', (tmp_image.width, tmp_image.height))
            img_data = img.load()
            for y in range(tmp_image.height):
                for x in range(tmp_image.width):
                    img_data[y,x] = calc_color(tmp_image.pixels[y*tmp_image.height + x])
        return img
```